# Does the faq tab work correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I like the idea of automatically generated FAQ lists. The mouseover text of the **faq** tab is *questions with the most links*. That's sounds sensible, links may come for example from duplicates or closely related questions.

So I had a look at the [{floats} faq.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats?sort=faq):

[image: floats question with the most links]

Number 5 of the list: [Article appendix with sections and toc entries in the form “Appendix A”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/article-appendix-with-sections-and-toc-entries-in-the-form-appendix-a) is a question which doesn't show any link to it in the right sidebar. The number of 88 views is also pretty low and indicates that this question is not very popular.

Number 6 of the list: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) shows 19 linked questions in the right sidebar. A result of the many links are its currently 2,612 views.

So, is the sort order for the faq tab correct, or is there a bug? I noticed a strange sort order also with other tags, though I guess this question with 19 links, and 9 duplicates pointing to it, is a good FAQ demonstration example.

**Update:** Right after I posted this question, that [Article appendix question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/article-appendix-with-sections-and-toc-entries-in-the-form-appendix-a) is listed at the top of the faq list:

[image: faq foir floats]

Still no links shown for this 1st place question, however the [question on the 3rd place](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures) shows 15 links.

The questions with many links, such as the mentioned frequently linked questions, are indeed very good FAQ candidates, so it would be great if this FAQ feature and the sorting would work.

Comment: Excellent question! I've been wondering how these FAQs are compiled, I guess I never noticed the mouseover text -- perhaps this should be made more obvious as well? The problem you're describing holds true for the [main faq](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq), too: While the [top question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) has a number of "linked questions", the [number three question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24672/presenting-a-long-linear-regression-equation) doesn't have any.

Comment: I even see a different order in the main faq. Now: 1. [biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) (14), 2. [\fil vs. \fill](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill) (2), 3. [MiKTeX package installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) (17). Doesn't mean that this shown number of links is the exact criterion, however it seems odd.

Comment: @doncherry: By making it "more obvious", are you referring to the number of linked posts, or just the sorting behaviour shown in the "mouseover text" for the FAQ ("questions with the most links" in this case)? I think the former - showing the number of linked posts, just like with the number of votes and/or views - might also be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Yes there was a bug there, and I am ashamed it has taken us so long to address this. I fixed it some time last week or the week before.

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood the way this sorting should work, but right now faq [no. 8](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday) has 13 linked questions, while [no. 9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) has 22+. Is this desired behavior?

Comment: something is weird, will look at it

Comment: @doncherry found it ... faq is only looking at question links, not answer links. will fix it now.

Comment: fixed now ... @doncherry

Comment: I'm afraid not ... [no. 8](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday) (14 links) -- [no. 9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) (>22 links). _But_ if I click on [see more linked questions…](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2ftex.stackexchange.com%2fquestions%2f9559%2f*%22) (at the latter question), I only get 7 results. There's an inconsistency somewhere.